# Шифрование диска с помощью Luks on LVM

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте. Есть сервер Centos 7 на который 2 диска. На втором диске есть данные и нужно зашифровать с помощью Luks но не потерять данные (cryptosetup -y luksFormat не делать). Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать.

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!
Есть варианты вроде [такого](https://www.johannes-bauer.com/linux/luksipc/), [такого](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto7) и на [русском](https://habrahabr.ru/post/169983/), но это все рисковано и вместо шифрования данных вы можете потерять все данные. Но попробовать можно :) Удачи!

p.s. Пример шифрования раздела без потери данных:

1. Отмонтируем наш диск `umount /dev/sda1`
2. Проверяем фс на ошибки:`e2fsck -f /dev/sda1`
3. Теперь необходимо уменьшить размер файловой системы: `resize2fs /dev/sda1 $size-10M` (10Mb должно хватить для загаловка LUKS)
4. Дальше сам процесс шифрования `luksConvert /dev/sda1` (тут варианты могут отличатся в зависимости от того чьим скриптом вы решите воспользоваться их придется качать и ставить не из официальных репов)

Comment: «тянет» максимум на комментарий: в ответе должна быть приведена ключевая информация, а ссылки стоит приводить лишь в качестве иллюстрации/допинформации.